# External SVG path in css Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I can use an external svg file for a path, e.g.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="defs.svg#icon-1"></use>
</svg>
```

In Firefox I can also do this with css, e.g.

```
clip-path: url(defs.svg#myClip);
```

But this doesn't work in Chrome, is there any work around for this?

Comment: Hi, I think it would be helpful if you could put up examples - including the svgs - so we can test any possible solutions easily.

Comment: Either fix [this Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212) or reference a clipPath that isn't external.